# AVCam Demo OverscanCompensation implementation

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation, avcam

I'm currently working with the AVCam demo app to present a live camera feed over airplay or apple hdmi adapter for import into a `HD` camera switcher.

The issue I'm having is with OverScanCompensation to remove the huge black border from the mirrored view.

The only documentation I have found is to implement the `screen.overscanCompensation = 3`; method someplace? I have tried to put it into `viewDidLoad` and it will let me, but it doesn't change anything on the external view?

I had success of sorts with the Airplay Demo (quellish) using `UIImagePicker`, but I would much prefer to implement `AVFoundation` for this exercise.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm looking for without having to implement separate view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, upon setting up the external screen (via, say, if ([[UIScreen screens] count] > 1) externalScreen = (UIScreen *)[[UIScreen screens] objectAtIndex:1];), set the overscanCompensation property of the above UIScreen instance to UIScreenOverscanCompensationInsetApplicationFrame (=2). It'll entirely get rid of both the border (overscanning) and image quality-deterioating scaling.

See http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/87/tv-display-output-why-does-your-picture-have-black-border-and-how-can-it-be-fixed for more info.